# How to unmount existing howl in React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, howler.js

I have a use case in which whenever a user goes to player page of my application and clicks on play button then a howl object is created and the sound plays but when user leaves that page and click play button for some other audio then previous sound keeps playing and top of that current sound also starts playing.

Here is the implementation:

```
const CustomPlayer = withCustomAudio(props => {
  let { currentTime, duration } = props;
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const sound = new Howl({ src: [props.streamUrl] });
  // localStorage.setItem("playing", JSON.stringify(sound));
  return (
    <>
      <div className="audioplayer">
        <div className="audioplayer-info">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              props.onTogglePlay(sound);
            }}
          >
            Play
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
});
```

Now in App js

```
const togglePlay = sound => {
    return sound.playing() ? sound.pause() : sound.play();
  };
```

I want to have controls in `App.js` file because I want audio to be played even if user goes to other pages of my application.

Any suggestions?